# Get additional data via $object->getData() without having to reload the object

Tags: magento-1.7, category, eav

I need to get the value of the *someValue* attribute for a *catalog/category* object that has already been loaded. Unfortunately the pre-loaded object does not include the *someValue* attribute. Here's how I am currently getting the value for the *someValue* attribute:

```
$someValue = $category->getData('someValue'); // returns NULL

// Since the above getData() call returns NULL, I have to reload the whole category
$category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
$someValue = $category2->getData('someValue'); // returns the desired value
```

Is there a more convenient way to grab the *someValue* attribute value without having to create a separate category object (*$category2*)? I feel this additional object adds quite a bit of overhead and might affect scalability.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you show the code that populates `$category`? I mean what you have before the line `$someValue = $category->getData('someValue');`/

Comment: The code where `$category` is populated is provided by a third-party extension that I'd rather not modify for various reasons (also it's heavily obfuscated but that's another story). So if you know a quick and effective way of getting this additional information I'd greatly appreciate it. :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a solution without seeing the code. What Sander suggests seams to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it is possible via the product model but should also work for categories since it uses the same extended class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract`.

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getAttributeRawValue($categoryId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. The method's documentation says `Retrieve attribute's raw value from DB.` so I'm guessing it must be quite a lightweight call?

Comment: Yup, as far as I know its a query that only touches one table. But its always better to extend the way your collection is fetched with an `addAttributeToSelect`